# Pass object from anonymous function inside DOM ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, anonymous-function, module-pattern

Q1: How can I load the **myApp object** from inside the **anonymous function** into the **DOM ready function**. I know one way to pass the object is using the **window.myApp = myApp**; inside the anonymous function but this exposes the myApp Object as a global object.

```
$(function(){
    //Load myApp inside here
});

(function(){
   var myApp = {
     //with properties inside
   }
}());
```

Q2:Also, I've seen the following **brackets inside** and **brackets outside**. What do they do?

```
(function(){
   var myApp = {
     //with properties inside
   }
}(brackets inside))(brackets outside);
```

Q3: I know its not possible but is there a **hack/trick** to load the anonymous function after DOM loads?

Comment: Couldn't you place `myApp` into DOM ready itself?

Comment: Having the `myWholeApp` singleton as a global object is not a problem.

Comment: I could do that but I am working to isolate all the core properties and methods inside the anonymous functions, and only use the DOM ready to manipulate the DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

May be like this:

```
(function () {
    var myApp = {
        //with properties inside
    }
    $(function () {
        // document is ready AND myApp is accessible
        myApp.init();
    });
}());
```

Regarding 2nd part of your question: placing invocation inside or outside the parenthesis does not make a difference. Some coders prefer one variant over the other. [Details here](http://jslinterrors.com/move-the-invocation-into-the-parens-that-contain-the-function/).

```
(function(){ /* do something */ })(); // invocation outside parenthesis
(function(){ /* do something */ }()); // invocation inside parenthesis
```

In case you are asking what does `()()` do; it invokes a function that returns a function and invokes the returned function. Consider this example and its output:

```
(function () {
    console.log("anonymous outer function");
    return function () {
        console.log("anonymous inner function");
    }
})()();

// output:
// anonymous outer function
// anonymous inner function
```